# Obtain the string in the first row and first column of a text file?

Tags: string, matlab, indexing, text-files

I am importing a text file into MATLAB and would like to call upon the string located in the first row and column of the text file. The string is something like this '923_0.png'. So it does contain both numbers and letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) to do this for you.  `textread` is usually defined in the following way:

```
data = textread('filename', 'delim');
```

`filename` is the file name of your text data while `delim` denotes format strings.  If your text follows a particular pattern, you can specify flags that will separate each line of your text data into multiple cells.  However, I believe your file has only file names that are stored in a single column.  As such, you can simply do this:

```
data = textread('text.txt', '%s');
```

`text.txt` would be the text file that you're reading in, while the `%s` delimiter reads the **each entire row** as a string.  If your file has `N` file names, `data` will be a `N x 1` cell array, where each element is the file name seen in each row.

You can then access the first row and first column by doing: `data{1}`.

Should your text file have **multiple** file names per row, that will be perfectly fine.  As long as each file name is space separated, each file name gets stored as an element in the cell array.  What will happen is that each file name gets stored in the column vector reading the text file from left to right and top to bottom.  As such, the first row, second column's file name can be accessed by `data{2}`, etc.